# Mensagem em JSON não aparece

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho esse meu código em PHP:

```
if($qryInsert == 1){
        //echo "Evento criado com sucesso!";
        echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Evento criado com sucesso!')); 
    }else{
        //echo "Erro ao criar evento";
        echo json_encode( array('status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Erro ao criar evento')); 
    }
```

no meu JS, está assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/evento.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status === '1') {
            $("#msg").val(data.status);
            $("#msg").show();
        }
    }
});
```

meu html...

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Acredito que o erro está no JS, mas onde?

Comment: Tens o `dataType` defenido para `JSON`? já testaste com numero `1` (sem aspas) e não string aqui: `data.status === '1'`? o que dá `console.log(data);`?

Comment: $.ajax({
         url: 'php/evento.php',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dataString,
         }

Comment: Ok, o `dataType` está certo. Testa `if(data.status == 1){` assim sem aspas e se não funcionar, diz o que dá  `success: function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data));}`?

Comment: Já tentei e não apareceu nada no console

Comment: Vou tentar esse seu alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Nem apareceu a mensagem do alert

Comment: Onde eu devo colocar o alert(...)? Antes ou depois do IF?

Comment: Antes do `if`, mas é o mesmo que `console.log(data)`... Vê o que aparece no developer tools do Browser na parte "Network"... e junta no jQuery `.fail(function(e) {
    alert(e);
  })` a ver se te dá mais info.

Comment: Onde e como, exatamente, eu uso o .fail(function(e){alert(e):})?

Comment: success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(data.status == 1){
               $("#msg").val(data.status);
               $("#msg").show();
            }
         }

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20960/discussion-between-sergio-and-gustavosevero).

Comment: Sobre o uso de JSON.stringfy, isso iria parsear um objeto em string, e, para parsea-lo novamente para objeto seria necessário utilizar JSON.parse. O retorno que o PHP gera é em string, então faz se necessário utilizar JSON.parse

Comment: verifique se o arquivo que imprime o json está com "UTF8 without bom" (ANSI-UTF8). Se possuir o caracter "BOM (byte order mark)", remova-o.

Answer (score 2):

É necessário parsear a resposta para JSON para assim conseguir acessar os atributos do seu objeto.

```
success: function(data){

            var resposta = JSON.parse(data);          

            if(resposta.status === '1'){
               $("#msg").val(resposta.status);
               $("#msg").show();
            }
         }
```

Comment: [Pelos vistos `console.log(data);` não dá nada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49949/mensagem-em-json-n%c3%a3o-aparece#comment101298_49949), então o problema está antes...

Comment: Oi pessoal, ainda preciso de uma ajuda no meu JS que não está mostrando o retorno do php:

$.ajax({
         url: 'php/evento.php',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dataString,

         success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            if(data.status == 1){
               $("#msg").val(data.status);
               $("#msg").show();
            }
         },
         error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      });

Comment: if($qryInsert == 1){
  //echo "Evento criado com sucesso!";
  echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Evento criado com sucesso!')); 
 }else{
  //echo "Erro ao criar evento";
  echo json_encode( array('status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Erro ao criar evento')); 
 }

Comment: Poste seu PHP e seu JS em um fiddle por favor

Comment: Oi @Fabricio.
Em que parte do fiddle eu coloco o php?
http://jsfiddle.net/gugasevero/f5f7w9vr/

Comment: @GustavoSevero: http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 0):

Veja bem,

```
resposta.status // Não vai te trazer o conteúdo da resposta, apenas seu status.
resposta.responseText //seria o ideal.
```

Outra coisinha,

```
$('#msg').html(resposta.responseText)// provavelmente seria mais apropriado pro seu div.
//Já que .val() é para preencher o atributo value=""
```